# Codeigniter session size and concurrent users

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have a question about codeigniter **sessions size**.
Is the session stored on **client side or server side**?
what about size limitation? I read some topics, and some developers said **4KB** and they said only session id is stored in browser. If this is true, what about **concurrent users**? I stored some data, like `user_id`, `username`, `user_first_name`, `user_last_name`, `user_avatar_name` using  **set_userdata** (and also some flashdata), instead of use queries in every page,  and use these values through the whole site. Now my question is about many concurrent users that want to logged in, in the same time and surf the site (like an online exam or anything). What about session size limitation? Is it considered for one user or all users?
can you explain me in detail?

thanks

Comment: What version of codeigniter? V2 & V3 handle session differently.

Comment: CodeIgniter version 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CodeIgniter 3+ session cookies are not used for data storage so the 4KB size is not an issue as it was for earlier versions. Session data (user and flash) is stored on the server and there are multiple storage drivers to choose from.

Sessions are, in essence, a "contract" between a (one) client and a server. The server agrees to "remember" the client and to hold some data for them. Each unique client gets their own "contract" and their own data storage space. The question of how many sessions can be instantiated depends on your server's configuration - how much memory and how much disc space is available.

*Session* concurrency is mostly about a (singular) user making many requests in a short period of time. It is not about lots of users hitting your site at the same time - that's a different kind of concurrency. Session concurrency can temporarily slow down a user's page load when lots of ajax requests are made to fetch data for the page. CodeIgniter is no more or less prone to this potential problem. Proper session management is required, which mostly boils down to closing the session once you no longer need anything from session variables.

Comment: Thanks a lot, dear DFriend discuss in details. So based on your explaining, I've no problem. I figure out that for one user, I stored about 130 Byte in sessions.

Comment: I see no problems - until you get tens of millions of hits all at once.